# uploading to heroku causes an error

Tags: heroku-toolbelt

Everytime I try and push my project to Heroku by using git push heroku master I get the following response. I have a macbook air OSX-10.8.

```
    -----> Ruby app detected
    -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
    -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
           New app detected loading default bundler cache
           Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs  vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
           Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
           Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
           Fetching git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git
           fatal: Could not parse object '9c6c07f74ff515cf38380b014cfede14a4f0eae4'.
           Git error: command `git reset --hard 9c6c07f74ff515cf38380b014cfede14a4f0eae4`
           in directory
           /tmp/build_260d9aa7-1d8e-4738-b10f-    fce9113dd86e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/bootstrap-sass-9c6c07f74ff5
           has failed.
           If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
           '/tmp/build_260d9aa7-1d8e-4738-b10f-fce9113dd86e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e'
           Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
           Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
           Fetching git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git
           fatal: Could not parse object '9c6c07f74ff515cf38380b014cfede14a4f0eae4'.
           Git error: command `git reset --hard 9c6c07f74ff515cf38380b014cfede14a4f0eae4`
           in directory
           /tmp/build_260d9aa7-1d8e-4738-b10f-fce9113dd86e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/bootstrap-sass-9c6c07f74ff5
       has failed.
       If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
       '/tmp/build_260d9aa7-1d8e-4738-b10f-fce9113dd86e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e'
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:fierce-taiga-8706.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:fierce-taiga-8706.git'
```

Here is are my git remotes

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:sheltered-crag-6550.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:sheltered-crag-6550.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:TheM00se/Pinteresting.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:TheM00se/Pinteresting.git (push
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'



gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', github: 'thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass', branch: '3'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

I've been trying to figure out a solution for 2 hours and really I'm not even sure what the problem is .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', github: 'thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass', branch: '3'
```

If you check the link below:

https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/branches

The branch seems to be deleted, maybe it was merged into the master branch, based on feedback from the OP, anyone using it subsequently should add the below to their Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2' # sass-rails needs to be higher than 3.2
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'
```

Comment: I replaced the line with the second and got an error message saying "Could not find gem 'boostrap-sass (>= 0) ruby' in
git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'boostrap-sass (>= 0) ruby'"

Comment: I followed the conventions laid out by Thomas Mcdonald and it worked.

Comment: I updated my answer for whoever needs it subsequently

Comment: Thank you so much, although another gem, the branch was indeed deleted.